# PocketSphinx - ALSA IOError: -9997 while trying to Decode Speech

Tags: python, pi-2, alsa, speech-recognition

I am trying to use Pocketsphinx for voice recognition. When I was trying to include it in python, using this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import environ, path

from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "pocketsphinx-5prealpha/model"
DATADIR = "pocketsphinx-5prealpha/test/data"

config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
decoder = Decoder(config)

import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

But when I run the file, I get an error from pyAudio saying Invalid Sample Rate. This is the output that I get:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Apparently, your sound device (whatever it is) does not support 16 kHz.

Comment: So, how can I reduce it? If i reduce it will it be ok?

Comment: Use a supported rate. I don't know your hardware, but try 48 or 44.1 kHz.

Comment: Yes... It worked when I put 44100.. Thanks! But now i have got the error input overflowed... i have checked with almost all of the questions. One said trying to change the chunk value but it didn't work for me when i put a few values... I will try... Can you give a solution??

Comment: You need a larger buffer size (as large as possible). But if your CPU is too slow, no amount of buffering will help.

Comment: So I should change this line ->   `buf = stream.read(1024)` to -> buf = 0??

Comment: `frames_per_buffer`

Comment: It didn't work... when i set stream.read(0) this was the result: http://pastebin.com/KpMA7zp0 . What can i do??

Comment: @AlokNaushad  It has been a while, but... buf = stream.read(1024, exception_on_overflow = False)  will work just fine - ignore the overflow.

Comment: To find what will work:  
`
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
samprate = p.get_device_info_by_index(0)['defaultSampleRate']
print("mic sample rate:",samprate)  
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=int(samprate), input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)`